# JavaScript code to filter and place elements starting in the top-left

Tags: javascript, html

I am 95% of the way done with what I would like to have this webpage do. On this [page](http://quantgov.org/topical-research-futureversion) I am looking to have my search bar filter the boxed options and fill them towards the top left. Right now, the boxes filter correctly and fill upwards (not quite sure why they filter upwards), but they don't fill upwards AND to the left. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: The snippet runs, but there is no container for the boxes where as squarespace naturally makes these.

```js
function search_topics() {
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
  let y = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-image _b1')

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      y[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      y[i].style.display = "table-cell";
    }
  }
```

```css
/* Main container */
.overlay-image {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Original image */
.overlay-image .image {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

/* Original text overlay */
.overlay-image .text {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2.0em;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 100%;
}

/* Text on hover formatting */
.overlay-image .text_2 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 100%;
}

/* New overlay on hover */
.overlay-image .hover {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* New overlay appearance on hover */
.overlay-image:hover .hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-image .normal {
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay-image:hover .normal {
 opacity: 0;
}



#searchbar{ 
    margin-left: 15%; 
    padding:15px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <input id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_topics()" type="text"
        name="search" placeholder="Search topics...."> 
</body>

<div class=" overlay-image _b1 ">
  <a href="url for block">
    <img class=" image _b2 " src="https://i.redd.it/m3u40szpez231.jpg" />
    <div class=" normal _b4 ">
      <div class="text">Title of a block</div>
    </div>
    <div class=" hover _b3 ">
      <div class=" text_2 ">Test that appears when block is hovered</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class=" overlay-image _b1 ">
  <a href="url for block">
    <img class=" image _b2 " src="https://i.redd.it/m3u40szpez231.jpg" />
    <div class=" normal _b4 ">
      <div class="text">Title of a block 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class=" hover _b3 ">
      <div class=" text_2 ">Test that appears when block is hovered</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your items move upward because the rows above are emptied of displayed content, allowing them to collapse. They don't move to the left because there are still table cells there. The problem you're having is that you're using a table to do work that tables were not designed to do. Css has a tool to do what you want called flexbox. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sky-9yyxf

```html
<body>
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="search"></input>
    <div id="options">
        <div value="coriander">Coriander</div>
        <div value="anise">Anise</div>
        <div value="lavender">Lavender</div>
        <div value="fennel">Fennel</div>
        <div value="ginger">Ginger</div>
        <div value="sage">Sage</div>
        <div value="cinnamon">Cinnamon</div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
import "./styles.css";

const search = document.getElementById("search");

if (search) {
  search.addEventListener("change", event => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      // Normalize the search term.
      const value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
      console.log(value);

      // Hide all non matching elements.
      document
        .querySelectorAll(`#options :not([value*=${value})`)
        .forEach(item => {
          item.classList.add("hidden");
        });

      // Show all matching elements.
      document.querySelectorAll(`#options [value*=${value}]`).forEach(item => {
        item.classList.remove("hidden");
      });
    } else {
      // If there are no search terms, show all elements.
      document.querySelectorAll(`#options div`).forEach(item => {
        item.classList.remove("hidden");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#options {
  /* Set the options to fit three items in a row, and wrap them. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* Setting max-width instead of width will allow your list to automatically adjust to smaller screen sizes. */
  max-width: 70em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#options div {
  /* Set the items to a fixed width */
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

#options div.hidden {
  /* Add a style to hide items when they don't apply to the search. */
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I ended up simply putting all of the blocks into a container, which I defined as a flex container. I then changed `table-cell` to `inline-flex` in my JavaScript and it worked perfectly. Even though I didn't use this code, it pointed me in the right direction!